# no matching editors or conversion strategy found after specifying transaction-manager bean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to this and am trying to create a Spring5 MVC/Hibernate5 web app but when I start Tomcat I get the following error:

The initial issue was to do with the transaction-manager, before adding the transaction-manager bean definition, the app started ok but failed with an error message saying it could not create the transaction thread.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/store.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210 implementing com.store.service.CustomerService,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'com.store.service.CustomerServiceImpl' for property 'customerService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210 implementing com.store.service.CustomerService,java.io.Serializable,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'com.store.service.CustomerServiceImpl' for property 'customerService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                             id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

        <description>
            Configuration file for the Store Application
        </description>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/store-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
          <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>store</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My Store-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.store.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <import resource="/spring/store.xml" />
    <import resource="/hibernate/hibernate-configuration.xml" />

</beans>
```

My hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/store" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="keeper" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="keeper123" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 5 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.store.vo.Make</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.store.vo.Model</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.store.vo.Car</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.store.vo.Customer</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.store.vo.CustomerCar</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


</beans:beans>
```

Comment: How is defined `customerService`? Can you also add `store.xml` code?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in your `CustomerController` class, you have injected not an interface, but the implementation of `CustomerService`, something like this:

```java
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerServiceImpl customerService;

}
```

The concrete class is proxied, so you should specify injection point as an interface instead:

```java
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, what a simple mistake to make, The concrete class was being injected but the Service classes also had the concrete class rather than the interface defined. Works a treat now

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I was injecting the concrete class into the Service class but the Service class also had the setter for the concrete class rather than the interface